# Error in PHP using if() on a MYSQL result containing no rows

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

EDIT:  Just to clarify, the query is correct - there are zero rows - the problem I am having is how to handle that in the PHP with the `IF`  basically I am iterating through rows (10 of them) some will have some data for the query and some won't.  The page falls over when a row doesn't.  Does that make any sense?

I know I'm doing something inherently wrong and I am sure the solution is simple...

MySQL query brings back `ZERO` rows;

```
SELECT * from tresults WHERE date = 'MAY2012'
```

I then have some PHP code as follows:

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    // do something
}
```

Now, as the query brings back `ZERO` rows, the page falls over on the `IF` statement...what am I doing wrong....

Comment: @Vague - yep, I'm sure it is correct - what I need to do however, is manage it so the page doesn't fall over - if that makes sense?  How does one deal with this?  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: @Devart - the DATE field isn't the issue, the query is running correctly and as it should.  The problem, I think is the way I'm handling (or not) the situation in PHP.

Comment: try `SELECT * from tresults WHERE date like '%MAY2012%'`

Comment: If you do not care if query returns any rows, you do not need an if statement..

Comment: use `while` instead of `if` statement...

Comment: What do you mean by "fall over"? Do you want the code inside the if block to execute or not? And does it execute? What do you get if you execute: print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result));

Comment: Step 1: ensure the query succeeded. Step 2: Ensure you got more than 0 rows back. Step 3: save the rows into an array and loop the array later on. Step 4: don't use `mysql_` functions, use PDO. It simplifies all the steps mentioned by a huge margin.

Comment: I am confused in `Now, as the query brings back ZERO rows, the page falls over on the IF statement...` more clarification please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the number of rows using [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
```

Or use while - note this will run for every row, if your query returns more than one row

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks @simonmayer - this is where it causes me a problem - I need it to be IF and not WHEN :( - I think I'm going to have re-code my page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from tresults WHERE date = 'MAY2012'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        //do stuff;
    }
```